# Want to uninstall Windows 8 and install Windows 7 Ultimate on a new Toshiba laptop. How?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, laptop, uninstall, windows-installation

I just purchased a Toshiba Laptop S855-068; I7-3630QM system with Windows 8. I would like to uninstall Windows 8 and install my licensed copy of Windows 7 Ultimate. I am going to be running CATIA (high end CAD software) which its not stable on Windows 8. I'm having trouble finding info and figuring out how to do this. Apparently its not as simple as I thought. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything on the laptop you care about?

If not:
Boot from the "windows 7 install DVD"
format the hard drive
and install windows
install updates
reboot
install more updates 
reboot

If yes:
Copy important stuff to USB device or somewhere not on the laptop and then do above.

Try slimdrivers  to get all the newest drivers for your devices.

Comment: Maybe I am a noob. When I restart the DVD it does spin up, but Win8 prompts to logon to the laptop. When this happens the boot up stops and win8 just launches. When I go to the DVD drive through My Computer I can select the setup.exe file. The install launches but within the first minute or so I get an error message. "Windows setup experienced an unexpected error. To install Windows restart the installation."

Comment: Im looking on the Toshiba site and google other procedures but having little success. All I need to do is get this laptop to boot from the DVD drive. I maybe a noob, but I won't try something I don't know anything about.

Comment: P.S. Its a brand new laptop. I won't be installing anything on this until Windows 7 is installed. I do not need to back up any files.